# How to get location by address in wp8 and display in AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, autocomplete, geolocation

I am developing wp8 application.  I would like to create AutoCompleteBox for quick search.
Here is my xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <maps:Map x:Name="MapWithMyLocation" Tap="mapWithMyLocation_Tap">
       </maps:Map>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox  x:Name="TxtSearch" TextChanged="TxtSearch_OnTextChanged" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here is my Event TxtSearch_OnTextChanged  on  AutoCompleteBox

```
 private void TxtSearch_OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtSearch.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Maps_GeoCoding(TxtSearch.Text);
        }
    }

    private async void Maps_GeoCoding(string sender)
    {
        var myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        var myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        var myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        MyGeoCoordinate =
            CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
        if (MyGeoCoordinate == null) return;
        var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery { SearchTerm = sender, GeoCoordinate = MyGeoCoordinate };
        var locations = await geoQuery.GetMapLocationsAsync();
        var items = new List<String>();
        var str = "";
        foreach (var item in locations)
        {
            str += item.Information.Address.City + " ";
            str += item.Information.Address.Street + " ";
            str += item.Information.Address.HouseNumber + " ";
            items.Add(str);
            str = "";
        }
        TxtSearch.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

But AutoCompleteBox display some wrong information or doesnt display. Any ideas?

Comment: what does it display?

Comment: @Sajeetharan For example I input "Los" ... its display nothing . Than I press delete and I have "Lo" .. and than its display Los Angeles

Comment: try setting valuememberpath property to your autocompletebox

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added ValueMemberPath="City"  and created class Address, but the same story. When I delete one letter it display City, Street and House number and that quickly disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Revwrote my function. Now I am getting only one item using FirstOrDefault. Here is example:

```
private async void Maps_GeoCoding(string sender)
    {
        var myAddress = new List<String>();
        var myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        var myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        var myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        MyGeoCoordinate =
            CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
        if (MyGeoCoordinate == null) return;
        var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery { SearchTerm = sender, GeoCoordinate = MyGeoCoordinate };
        var locations = await geoQuery.GetMapLocationsAsync();
        var location = locations.FirstOrDefault();
        if (location != null)
        {
            myAddress.Add(location.Information.Address.City + " " + location.Information.Address.Street + " " + location.Information.Address.HouseNumber);
            MapWithMyLocation.Center = location.GeoCoordinate;
        }
        TxtSearch.ItemsSource = myAddress;
    }
```

XAML is the same as in question.